# Run Flask dev server over HTTPS using CLI

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to serve a Flask application over HTTPS using the `flask` command. I can do this using `app.run` by passing the `ssl_context` argument, but I can't figure out how to do this on the CLI.

```
flask run --host='0.0.0.0' --port=80
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[This will be available when Flask 1.0 is released.](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/2606)

```
flask run --cert dev.crt --key dev.key
```

Until then, use `app.run` if you really need this. Keep in mind that the dev server is not meant for production and should typically not be accessible publicly, so SSL shouldn't be as big a concern.

Answer (score 4):

I would personally use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to create secure tunnels to localhost. Like davidism stated the dev server isn't meant for production but if you want see how your app behaves and/or your app requires SSL (like FlaskAsk apps for example) [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) is the probably the easiest way.