# Testing HTTPS in Flask using self-signed certificates made through openssl

Tags: python, ssl, flask

I just ran the following command to generate self-signed certificates:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365
```

After executing the commands I answered a handful of questions about my locality etc. There were no errors when generating the certificates. I then added `app.run(ssl_context=('cert.pem', 'key.pem'))` to my Flask application.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    """ Home page of the website """
    return render_template('index.html')


... Some other functions ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(ssl_context=('cert.pem', 'key.pem'))
```

The problem is that nothing is delivered over HTTPS. When I run the app I get:

```
$ flask run
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
```

I can visit pages fine with HTTP but the minute I try to do HTTPS I get the following error on my browser:

```
An error occurred during a connection to XXXXXXX.XXX.edu:5000. 
SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

And I get the following error on my server:

```
code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('\x16\x03\x01\x00\xbd\x01\x00\x00\xb9\x03\x03\xbc\x1c\xc6q#\xdcr')
```

Why can't I view content using HTTPS?

*Disclaimer: I know if one wants to do production level coding they should use nginx or gunicorn to serve HTTPS. I am currently trying to use Flask just for testing's sake.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your exact code runs just fine for me in both Python 2.7.12 and Python 3.5.2.

Also, from the server error i can tell your server expects a plain HTTP request right, not a TLS handshake.

`\x16\x03\x01..` is the start of a **ClientHello** packet which says *hey server, let's start a TLS channel, here are some crypto bits*.

Your server seems to try to interpret that as an HTTP request, that's why you see the `HTTP 400 Bad request`. This is even more evident from the CLI output that you posted in the comments:

> When the application actually starts up, it says `Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/`.

Note the `http` instead of `https`.

Long story short, there's something wrong with your Python/Flask installation. Try to reinstall Python from scratch.

#### UPDATE

I missed the part where you said you're running with `flask run` and not `python app.py`. Seems that only the former spins up a TLS listener.

Either `flask run` simply can't do TLS or there's an undocumented parameter that we need to pass in, which would make zero sense.

#### UPDATE #2

The answer is here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48468045/4148708

Comment: When I run my flask app on the server using `python app.py` I get the correct response -- `Running on https://127.0.0.1:5000/` but when I run it using `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` it doesn't work. I tried reinstalling python.

Comment: Ooops, i missed that part - yes, it listens on `http` if i do `flask run`. No idea, maybe that's by design? Can't find a parameter that would kick off TLS.

Comment: I believe `flask run` is more of a debugger than a real server? Would be great if someone would chip in here with the right amount of detail.

Comment: Check my updated answer for the.. updated answer :)